# Как сделать плавное движение фона?

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container.loading:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.55), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.55), rgba(0,0,0,1));
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 2.5s ease infinite;
  z-index: 10;
}
@keyframes gradient{
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  25% {
    background-position: 25% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
  }
  75% {
    background-position: 75% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">123</div>
<div class="container loading">123</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я осмелюсь предположить, что вы добиваетесь такого результата.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container.loading:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.55), rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.55), rgba(0,0,0,1));
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 2.5s ease infinite;
  z-index: 10;
}
@keyframes gradient{
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">123</div>
<div class="container loading">123</div>
```